# The playable structure I am making in HTML falls flat, and the common attribute is not helping

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics

I am trying to make a game in **HTML** with **Java** at the same time, and I do not know exactly how to color/paint the `<canvas>` element. Here is what I have so far with my game:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var myScore;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.05;
    myScore = new component("30px", "Consolas", "black", 280, 40, "text");
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type == "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
        this.hitBottom();
    }
    this.hitBottom = function() {
        var rockbottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        if (this.y > rockbottom) {
            this.y = rockbottom;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            return;
        } 
    }
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 20;
        maxHeight = 200;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 50;
        maxGap = 200;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, height, "green", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(10, x - height - gap, "green", x, height + gap));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>
<button onmousedown="accelerate(-0.2)" onmouseup="accelerate(0.05)">ACCELERATE</button>
<p>Use the ACCELERATE button to stay in the air</p>
<p>How long can you stay alive?</p>
</body>
```

## Why I want to color the canvas

The reason WHY i want to color the canvas is because I want to add a background, because this WILL be a public unofficial game. You can clearly see that the popular game: "Doodle Jump" (No clickbait) has a decent background color.

> I want to be creative with my game, not lazy.

---

All in all, is `<canvas>` the best element? If so, how can I change the color of the background with *CSS*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zc0othj9/) with your code. In the fiddle I changed the background-color to yellow and it works.

You can also make the background of the canvas a different color by drawing a colored rectangle onto the canvas which has the same width and height as the canvas element. Just make sure to draw this rectangle before you draw anything else. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
 // specify color
this.context.fillStyle = "red";
// draw a rectangle with the same width and height as canvas
this.context.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
```